# Slide Widget to left

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make this Card Widget go from this position to completely right till its not visible using animation.

[image]

How can I do that?

Later I will be adding more cards below and want them go left, up and down too, currently it's only for one card.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Swipe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwipeState createState() => _SwipeState();
}

class _SwipeState extends State<Swipe> {
  //bool bgColor = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: bgColor ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 30, 40, 0),
                height: 140,
                width: 400,
                child: Card(
                  child: Center(child: Text("RIGHT")),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use AnimatedContainer with `Align` right and `Visibility` widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget called `Dismissible`. Example:

```
Dismissible(
  onDismissed: (direction) {
     onWidgetRemove();
  },
  confirmDismiss: (direction) {
     return confirmRemoveWidget();
  },
  key: ValueKey(someItemId),
  child: MyWidget())
```

Note that `key` must not be `null`. `confirmDismiss` is optional and usually used with dialog to confirm action.

Small tip: Rather than using `SingleChildScrollView`+`Column` use `ListView`